# if class is hidden then add class to id with javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript

I am new here, sorry if I do some mistake with this question. I am tired of trying, how to add class to id if class hidden using javascript (no jquery). Here is what I have tried so far.

```js
function hidekeep() {
    document.getElementById("keep-ads").style.display = "none"
}
setTimeout(function () {
    var e = document.getElementById("keep-ads"),
    t = document.getElementsByClassName("adsbygoogle");
    if(t.style.display = "none") {
        e.className += "up";
    }
}, 2e3);
```

```css
.up {color:red;}
.adsbygoogle {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="keep-ads">Foo1
</div>
<div class="adsbygoogle">Bar1
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/31smppgv/2/)

Comment: `if(t.style.display = "none")` should be `if(t.style.display == "none")`.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array

Comment: Not quite an array, but an `HTMLCollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript, `=` is an assignment operator, where as `==` is a comparision operation.

**So change your bloc to  this:**

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var e = document.getElementById("keep-ads"),
    t = document.getElementsByClassName("adsbygoogle")[0]; // assuming there's just one element with the given class name
    if(t.style.display == "none") { // changed here
        e.className += "up";
    }
}, 2e3);
```

**UPDATE:**

> how to add class to id if class hidden using javascript

Use `element.style.display = 'none';` to hide an element and read the `style.display` property of the element.

```js
function hidekeep() {
    document.getElementById("keep-ads").style.display = "none"
}
setTimeout(function () {
    var e = document.getElementById("keep-ads"),
    t = document.getElementsByClassName("adsbygoogle")[0]; // assuming there's just one element with the given class name

    if(t.style.display == 'none') { // changed here
        e.className += "up";
    }
}, 2e3);

var hideBar1 = function() {
     document.getElementsByClassName("adsbygoogle")[0].style.display = 'none';

};

document.getElementsByClassName("hide-ads")[0].addEventListener('click', hideBar1 , false);
```

```css
.up {color:red;}
```

```html
<div id="keep-ads">Foo1
</div>
<div class="adsbygoogle">Bar1
</div>

<button class="hide-ads">
HIDE
</button>
```

Comment: how about using height? I've tried it, but it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/bt3Lo9fc/

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection object, not a single element (like `document.getElementById` does). So when you check for `t.style`, it's not there. You would want to something more like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("adsbygoogle").forEach(function(t) {
    if (t.style.display === 'none') e.className += 'up';
});
```